# MySql Query - Getting messages at top for the users I am following and sorted date wise

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a messages table.

```
postId |  createDateTime         |  userId  |  message
 3     |  2011-04-11 07:08:46    |    3     |  A     
 4     |  2011-04-11 08:08:46    |    1     |  B      
 5     |  2011-04-13 09:08:46    |    3     |  C      
 6     |  2011-04-14 09:08:46    |    2     |  D   
 7     |  2011-04-14 10:08:46    |    1     |  D
```

The 2nd table holds the data of the Followers (To whome user has follows):

```
  ID   |    userId      |following|
   1   |      60        |   1     |
   2   |      60        |   2     |
   3   |      48        |   1     |
```

I need a query that outputs messages of the users whom I had followed at the top date wise. Like if the user who queries has ID 60 and follows 1 and 2 then the results should be

```
postId |  createDateTime         |  userId  |  message
 7     |  2011-04-14 10:08:46    |    1     |  D     
 6     |  2011-04-14 09:08:46    |    2     |  D       

 4     |  2011-04-11 08:08:46    |    1     |  B  

 5     |  2011-04-13 09:08:46    |    3     |  C      
 3     |  2011-04-11 07:08:46    |    3     |  A
```

As the rows that have userId 3 are at bottom because the user 60 did not follow userId 3. However, the user id 1 and 2 which are at top are sorted in such a way that the 2nd level sort is only sorted by date in desc order.

I have created a query for this but it has an issue, It did not sort properly on date.

```
SELECT m.postId,m.updateDateTime,m.userId, m.message, f.followerId, f.userId
FROM messages m 
left join followers f on m.userId = f.followerId  and f.userId=60
order by f.followerId desc, m.updateDateTime desc;
```

The desired result should output userIds whole I have followed at top with date wise in desc order.

[image: Results of query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably reverse the order conditions :

```
SELECT m.postId, m.createDateTime, m.userId, m.message, f.followerId, f.userId
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN followers f on m.userId = f.followerId and f.userId=60 
ORDER BY f.userId desc, m.createDateTime desc, f.followerId desc
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was missing. Thanks. reversing and adding f.userId in sort order has given the desired results.

Comment: Glad to hear :)